# Does SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery escape the selectionArgs (is it safe)?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-injection

Checking the [rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) docs, I don't see any explicit statement about `selectionArgs` escaping.

So should I sanitize the `selectionArgs` ahead, or is it safe to assume the rawQuery will use any `selectionArgs` values in safe way, avoiding SQL Injection?

I'm interested into Android API 14+ implementations, I don't care about any security bugs in old 1.x and 2.x ROMs.

(I'm not talking about the first `String sql` parameter, that one looks obviously vulnerable, but I would expect the args to be sanitized, yet there's no documentation about it on developer.android.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selection args use sqlite's [variable binding](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) and they are never part of the SQL itself. No sanitization is needed.

---

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) is actually misleading here:

> You may include `?`s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from `selectionArgs`. The values will be bound as Strings.

The first sentence would indicate some sort of string replacement happening while there is no string replacement going on actually. The latter sentence refers to (variable) binding which is correct, and for which there's e.g. [`SQLiteProgram`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html) and its `bindAllArgsAsStrings()` between `SQLiteDatabase` and the sqlite C API.